# Possible moderator mistake

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

Just found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57891646/549372), which had been deleted by a moderator, who might have thought it's a "link only" answer - but it actually answers the question, because it is about query-string parameters for an API. Of course I could post the link into a new answer and add some fluff, but I rather think it should be un-deleted and receive the bounty, because the XML looks quite alike what the OP has asked for (the continuation of the API was not the question and I could not even verify that claim).

The posted URL (for those who cannot see the answer):

```
https://news.google.com/rss?q=studie&hl=de-DE&gl=DE&ceid=DE:de
```

Comment: Looks like I screwed up, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

This answer has now been un-deleted. You can also flag the post to bring the issue to our attention and most likely another moderator will review the post.